# Jupyter launch error from Ananconda in my mac

Tags: python, macos, jupyter-notebook, anaconda

I'm getting the below error while launching Jupyter notebook from Ananconda, any ideas how to resolve this?

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/Users/ajaaykannanvr/anaconda3/bin/jupyter-notebook", line 7, in 
from notebook.notebookapp import main
File "/Users/ajaaykannanvr/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/notebook/notebookapp.py", line 78, in 
from .services.kernels.kernelmanager import MappingKernelManager, AsyncMappingKernelManager
File "/Users/ajaaykannanvr/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/notebook/services/kernels/kernelmanager.py", line 18, in 
from jupyter_client.session import Session
File "/Users/ajaaykannanvr/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/jupyter_client/**init**.py", line 4, in 
from .connect import *
File "/Users/ajaaykannanvr/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/jupyter_client/connect.py", line 21, in 
import zmq
File "/Users/ajaaykannanvr/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/zmq/**init**.py", line 47, in 
from zmq import backend
File "/Users/ajaaykannanvr/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/zmq/backend/**init**.py", line 40, in 
reraise(*exc_info)
File "/Users/ajaaykannanvr/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/zmq/utils/sixcerpt.py", line 34, in reraise
raise value
File "/Users/ajaaykannanvr/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/zmq/backend/**init**.py", line 27, in 
_ns = select_backend(first)
File "/Users/ajaaykannanvr/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/zmq/backend/select.py", line 26, in select_backend
mod = **import**(name, fromlist=public_api)
File "/Users/ajaaykannanvr/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/zmq/backend/cython/**init**.py", line 6, in 
from . import (constants, error, message, context,
ImportError: dlopen(/Users/ajaaykannanvr/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/zmq/backend/cython/error.cpython-36m-darwin.so, 2): Library not loaded: @rpath/libsodium.23.dylib
Referenced from: /Users/ajaaykannanvr/anaconda3/lib/libzmq.5.dylib
Reason: image not found
Saving session...
...copying shared history...
...saving history...truncating history files...
...completed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some dependencies that are not working correctly as mentioned here https://github.com/jupyter/notebook/issues/1632
Try the following:

```
conda remove zeromq
conda install zeromq
```